# Counting results from my curl command in bash

Tags: bash, curl, servicenow

I am running a curl command that connects with my ServiceNow PDI. I am trying to pull all the records from the Incident table and print out how many there are.
Additionally my code takes input from a file and loops thru the list of keywords and then searches for which record's description contains the keyword

```
while IFS= read -r string
do
    curl --user admin:password "https://dev000000.service-now.com/incident.do?CSV&sysparm_query=descriptionLIKE"$( echo "$string" | sed 's/ /%20/g' )"&sysparm_fields=number&sysparm_limit=1000&sysparm_count_number=true"
```

my keywords.txt looks something like:

```
email
server
hard drive
```

right now my code successfully loops thru keywords, handles the white space exception, and prints the records, but i would like to print the total records that contain each keyword like this:

```
3, email
7, server
2, hard drive
```

Comment: Count the total number of times "email" is in keywords.txt or are you wanting to count something from the output of curl? What does the output look like?

Comment: First of all, you have to urlencode the keywords (i.e. `hard%20drive`)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano yes i used ```sysparm_query=descriptionLIKE"$( echo "$string" | sed 's/ /%20/g' )"``` to cancel out the whitespaces

Comment: @jordanm i would like the number of records that contain the word "email" in the short description

Comment: @jordanm the current ouput prints the record number of each records that contains each word like:
email
"number"
"INC0009005"
"INC0000060"
"INC0000058"
"INC0000047"
"INC0000032"
"INC0000021"
"INC0000017"
"INC0000013"
"INC0000012"
"INC0000004"
"INC0000001"
server
"number"
"INC0007001"
"INC0000060"
"INC0000039"
"INC0000033"
"INC0000016"
"INC0000002"
sap
"number"
"INC0000055"
"INC0000053"
"INC0000052"
"INC0000051"
"INC0000044"
"INC0000029"
"INC0000018"
"INC0000009"
hard drive
"number"
"INC0000028"
"INC0000026"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grep` command with the `-c` option to count the result and then pass it to the `awk` command like the below to print your output:

```
while IFS= read -r string
do
    curl "https://foor.bar?string" | grep -c "$string" | awk -v string=$string '{print $1, string}'
done < keywords.txt
```

Comment: its returning "0, application" "0, server" for each keyword.

Comment: also, i should clarify, i am searching for the amount of records returned that contain the keyword, not the amount of times the keyword appears in the record. sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a curl for every keyword. Flip the paradigm.

```
mapfile -t keys < keywords.txt
declare -A lookup=()
while read -r line; do
  for k in "${keys[@]}"; do
    case "${line,,}" in *"${k,,}"*) ((lookup[$k]++));; esac
  done
done < <(curl --user admin:password "https://dev000000.service-now.com/incident.do?CSV&sysparm_query=descriptionLIKE"$string"&sysparm_view=ess" --proxy http://sub.proxy.att.com:8080 -k)
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do echo "${lookup[$k], $k"; done
```

This doesn't url-encode though, you should probably do that in your file, as mentioned elsewhere. Likewise, I downcased everything for a `case` match which may not be your best bet here. YMMV.

You can make it a lot faster (probably) by putting the whole logic into `awk`.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{lookup[$0]=0; next}
     { for (k in lookup) { if ($0 ~ k) { lookup[k]++ } } }
     END{ for (k in lookup) { print lookup[k]", "k } }' keywords.txt <(curl ... )
```

If you have trouble with getting the syntax right, you *can* just use a tempfile.
You can also do case-insensitive searches by adding a `BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}`.

```
curl "${yourArgs[@]}" >tmpfile &&
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} NR==FNR{lookup[$0]=0; next}
     { for (k in lookup) { if ($0 ~ k) { lookup[k]++ } } }
     END{ for (k in lookup) { print lookup[k]", "k } }' keywords.txt tmpfile
```

`mktemp` is better, but I didn't want to add complications.

Comment: for some reason, anytime i try code that includes parenthesis, i get an error "syntax error: unexpected "(""